# Transactions in SQLITE Android

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

Is there anything like asp.net transactions in Android SQLite? I am doing some processing on an SQLite database from my Android code, but I want upon failure to **rollback** the transaction and return the database to it's original state before the processing started.

Can this be achieved?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already there in the methods provided by the framework.

Check the SQLiteDatabase class docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Specifically what you want are the `*WithOnConflict` methods and use the constant `CONFLICT_ROLLBACK` in said methods.

> When a constraint violation occurs, an immediate ROLLBACK occurs, thus
>   ending the current transaction, and the command aborts with a return
>   code of SQLITE_CONSTRAINT